# Virtualize linux SD-card to xencenter

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines, xenserver

I have an SD card which contains the root of a physical linux machine. I would like to make a virtual server out of this SD.

Preferably without having to run this SD card on a physical linux machine and using the clonezilla method.

I would like to end up with a VHD, OVA or OVF so I can import this into Xencenter

So far I have installed an ext2 volume manager to be able to read/write the SD card (on windows). I have made a VHD out of this by using disk2vhd (from microsoft) but when I import this into xencenter, the VM halts on the boot loader.

It recognizes the harddisk as a boot device but it does not continue from there. Running in recovery mode skips the harddrive and attempts boot from network for some reason, which errors into 'no bootable devices'

Any help is kindly appreciated!

Comment: How did that physical Linux machine boot?

Comment: it booted from the same SD card that I have now

Comment: Yes, but how? What is the boot process?

Comment: I honestly don't know, this is beyond my linux knowledge

Comment: There's a lot to know. Take a crash course with [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting).

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar problem with an old Ubuntu 10.04 server, so i made an image (using Acronis Trueimage) and restored in a Virtualbox machine, worked. After this i export in ova (1.0) format and imported at Xencenter (version 7.1 in that time).

[Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYPYp.png)

[Parametres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYif1.png)